# Aerospike how to detect stale connections in java client

Tags: timeout, aerospike, stale

My java application uses an Aerospike client to connect to a cluster in the cloud. For some reason the cluster went down and we created a new cluster. My java client has stale connections ( which are still trying to connect to the old cluster). Only an application restart fixed the problem. Is there a way to detect stale connections, drop them and re-establish new connections

After aerospike cluster went down, restarted my application. Expected connections to be automatically re-established

Comment: How did you seed the client? If the client loses connections to all nodes in the cluster, it is supposed to fall back to the seeds and, if those are, for example, a round robin DNS that was then updated or a load balancer that would end up on a node in the new cluster, it should re-connect as far as I know.

Comment: We use multiple seed nodes ( round robin dns)

Comment: Subscribing to the log facility of the client library should shed some light then. Assuming your round robin dns would re-resolve to IPs of the new cluster, the client should fall back to re-resolving the DNS when losing access to all the nodes of the original cluster.